# How do I output a number of HTML elements from an int?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a PHP page with an int that can be from 1-4

I want to output that number of stars. Is there anything shorter than writing a for loop to do that?

Something with a syntax like `<?= print($num,"*") ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str_repeat):

```
<?= str_repeat("*", $num); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str_repeat):

```
echo str_repeat( "*", $num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str_repeat ( string $input , int $multiplier )
```